# Retrieve domain name and path using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, redirect, domain-driven-design, dns

I need to fetch the domain name and path from the request to provide the following return values:

```
domain1.com/default.aspx    returns      domain1.com/default.aspx
domain1.com/                returns      domain1.com/
domain1.com                 returns      domain1.com
```

At the moment every URL fetch function I try seems to return `domain.com/default.aspx` no matter what the address bar in my browser says.  Any solution to this?

I've tried lots of different built-in functions to retrieve parts of the request but none seem to provide the desired results.

Comment: I might be wrong but yours problem would be solved if you compare retrieven page name to `String.Empty` ( that means user typed in browser only domain name).

Comment: Yes but what function can retrieve the page name as blank when it isn't specified?  All of them seem to return default.aspx at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to your problem.

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`will return a `Uri` object that contains all the parts of the URL broken down for you. From that, you should be able to get what you're looking for. Specifically, the property you want is [Uri.Authority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx).

EDIT: Try something like this:

```
    public static string GetPath(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        var authority = request.Url.Authority;
        var pathAndQuery = request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        var query = request.Url.Query;
        var path = pathAndQuery.Substring(0, 
                       pathAndQuery.Length - query.Length));

        if (!authority.EndsWith("/"))
            authority += "/";

        return authority + path;
    }
```

Comment: URI authority only seems to return the domain name.

Comment: See edit above. (Haven't tested, but should be in the ballpark.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a single website within IIS with multiple bindings/host headers for your domains, and remove **default.aspx** from the default documents. You *should* then be able to use the `urlMappings` configuration element to facilitate your redirects. If you need more information on the urlMappings check out this link: http://dotnetperls.com/urlmappings-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

You could create an HttpModule for each domain - implement the Application_BeginRequest event like so:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    // get context and file path
    HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)source).Context;
    string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;

    if (filePath.Equals("/"))
    {
        // redirect to products page
        context.Response.Redirect(filePath + "products.aspx");
    }
}
```

This should redirect http://www.domain1.com/ to http://www.domain1.com/products.aspx - requests for http://www.domain1.com/default.aspx should not redirect.

Answer (score -1):

please provide default document in IIS, and it will work in same manner as you want. so your can set `products.aspx` in `domain1.com`'s default document and in `domain2.com` make it `categories.aspx` and it will be all set.

Comment: I need a programatic solution not one via IIS